# Linux port forwarding using another port

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

i have a server that uses linux (centos) without root access, i want to know if i can forward a port 10000 to localhost:3306 using ssh or without installing any software?

so that when i access that server on port 10000, it will connect to that computer's localhost port 3306..

normally i would use Pound, but on that server i don't have root access.. how to do this using ssh?

Comment: All you really need is a TCP proxy.  Non-root processes should be able to bind to port 10000 if it isn't already in use.

Answer (score 1):

(assuming you are talking about OpenSSH):

You connect with SSH from $computer to $server, and give as parameter: "-R10000:localhost:3306". If you want to connect with other computers to $servers, you have
to take a look into the `sshd` configuration file, for the option `GatewayPorts`, which enables this kind of access.

Read the `ssh` manpage for more details, you can also decide not to run a command on the other side (so not get a shell) and more (http://www.openssh.org/manual.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can run [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/socat-version2.html) which also supports multiple connections. No need for root, you can run it as a normal user.